# Expansion of composition functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are continuously differentiable over a closed interval $[a,b]$. I want to know how to prove that there exists a polynomial $F$ with integer coefficients such that

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx} \Big(f\big(1-g(x)\big) - (1-x)\Big) = F\big(f(x),f'(x),g(x),g'(x)\big).
\end{equation}

Basically, this means that we could "expand" the function (which involves a composition of two functions) on the left-hand side by a function that can be written as the "product" of individual terms. Here $f'$ and $g'$ are derivatives of $f$ and $g$, respectively. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

All you can get by differentiation is

$$-g'(x)f'(1-g (x))+1$$